# While trying to clone aws repo it is not asking for credentials and showing error

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

I am trying to clone below aws repo:
https://git-codecommit.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/soumenTestRepo

I am using command:

```
git clone https://git-codecommit.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/soumenTestRepo
```

It is **not prompting for credentials** and showing following error:

```
Cloning into 'soumenTestRepo'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/soumenTestRepo/': Failed to connect to git-codecommit.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com port 443: Timed out
```

I have already tried all these fixes mentioned in this documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-ch.html#troubleshooting-windowshttps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused due to network issue. It wasn't allowing to connect get data from GitHub. We can use eclipse to clone repository.